# how can i give the COMMIT in my script...?

Tags: bash, sqlite

How can i define the commit in the following shell script..?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " --- Enter the Database name ---"
read databasename

echo " --- enter the table name --- "
read table_name



sqlite3 $databasename.db "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name;"

sqlite3 $databasename.db  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name(cus_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,cus_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ,cus_domain TEXT UNIQUE, cus_status TEXT NOT NULL,Port INTEGER NOT NULL);"


echo " --- Enter the total number of customer records do you want ---"
read cus_count


echo "--- Enter the following details one by one---"

port_num=8080
declare -a customer

for((i=1;i<=cus_count;i++))
do

echo "enter the $i customer details"

echo "---Enter the customer name---"
read c_name


customer=$(sqlite3 $databasename.db "select cus_name from $table_name");

for cus in "${customer[@]}"
do

c_domain="$c_name"

if [[ "$c_name" != "$customer" ]]

then
    echo "---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---"
    read c_status

if [[ "$port_num" == "$port_num" ]]; then
       port_num=$(($port_num + 1))


sqlite3 $databasename.db "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name (cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.in\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;"
sqlite3 $database.db ".read SQLTableTransfer"


fi

else
    echo "!!!OOPS you entered customer name already available!!!"
    echo "---Please enter new customer name---"

i=$(($i - 1))

fi
done
done

echo " --- Records from the $table_name ---"

sqlite3 $databasename.db "select * from $table_name;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sqlite3, Autocommit mode is on by default. Autocommit mode is disabled by a BEGIN statement and re-enabled by a COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

In your script, you may use echo command to define BEGIN statement and COMMIT.

Eg: - instead of

`sqlite3 $databasename.db "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name(cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.in\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;"`

Use

`echo 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name(cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.in\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;COMMIT;' | sqlite3 $databasename.db`

or

`sqlite3 $databasename.db "BEGIN TRANSACTION;INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name (cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.in\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;COMMIT;"`

Comment: i get these error @ukrisp Error: near line 1: unrecognized token: "$table_name(cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status,"@ukrisp

Comment: try this  `sqlite3 $databasename.db "BEGIN TRANSACTION;INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name (cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.in\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;COMMIT;"` instead of `echo 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name(cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.in\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;COMMIT;' | sqlite3 $databasename.db`

Comment: sqlite3 $databasename.db "BEGIN TRANSACTION;INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name(cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.in\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;COMMIT;"  i give this type

Comment: please help me for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801144/

Comment: @Mahendranatarajan if the issue is solved , can u marked it solved by clicking the tick mark. This will help other isers