# i want to check the all customer name values with the respective given value(c_name)

Tags: bash, sqlite

In my script, the Customer name is not compared correctly in the for loop.please fix my issue.
{
    #!/bin/bash

```
echo " --- Enter the Database name ---"
read databasename

echo " --- enter the table name --- "
read table_name



sqlite3 $databasename.db "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name;"


sqlite3 $databasename.db  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name(cus_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,cus_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ,cus_domain TEXT UNIQUE, cus_status TEXT NOT NULL,Port INTEGER NOT NULL);"


echo " --- Enter the total number of customer records do you want ---"
read cus_count


echo "--- Enter the following details one by one---"

port_num=8080
declare -a customer

for((i=1;i<=cus_count;i++))
do

echo "enter the $i customer details"

echo "---Enter the customer name---"
read c_name


customer=$(sqlite3 $databasename.db "select cus_name from $table_name;")



for cus in "${customer[@]}"
do

c_domain="$c_name"

if [[ "$c_name" != "$customer" ]]

then
    echo "---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---"
    read c_status

if [[ "$port_num" == "$port_num" ]]; then
       port_num=$(($port_num + 1))

sqlite3 $databasename.db "BEGIN TRANSACTION;INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name(cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.in\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;COMMIT;" 

fi

else
    echo "!!!OOPS, you entered customer name already available!!!"
    echo "---Please enter new customer name---"

i=$(($i - 1))

fi
done
done

echo " --- Records from the $table_name ---"

sqlite3 $databasename.db "select * from $table_name;"}
```

Output 1:

mahendranatarajan@amachu-Inspiron-3558:~$ ./new2.sh

--- Enter the Database name ---

demo

--- enter the table name ---

demo_table

--- Enter the total number of customer records do you want ---

3

--- Enter the following details one by one---

enter the 1 customer details

---Enter the customer name---

ABC

---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---

Active

enter the 2 customer details

---Enter the customer name---

ABC

!!!OOPS you entered customer name already available!!!

---Please enter new customer name---

enter the 2 customer details

---Enter the customer name---

BCD

---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---

Active

enter the 3 customer details

---Enter the customer name---

ABC

---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---

Active

--- Records from the demo_table ---

1|ABC|abc.in|Active|8081

2|BCD|bcd.in|Active|8082

mahendranatarajan@amachu-Inspiron-3558:~$

here I give first value as "ABC" then second value as "ABC" then it shows the warning message correctly. but the following output I give first value as "ABC" then second value as "BCD" then third value as "ABC" but I cant get the warning message properly.what can I do for that issue..?

Output 2:

mahendranatarajan@amachu-Inspiron-3558:~$ ./new2.sh

--- Enter the Database name ---

demo

--- enter the table name ---

demo_table

--- Enter the total number of customer records do you want ---

3

--- Enter the following details one by one---

enter the 1 customer details

---Enter the customer name---

ABC

---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---

Active

enter the 2 customer details

---Enter the customer name---

BCD

---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---

Active

enter the 3 customer details

---Enter the customer name---

ABC

---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---

Active

--- Records from the demo_table ---

1|ABC|abc.in|Active|8081

2|BCD|bcd.in|Active|8082

mahendranatarajan@amachu-Inspiron-3558:~$

Comment: Please reformat your output using markdown for the purpose of readability.

Comment: @Yunnosch done..

Comment: try `if [[ "$c_name" != "$cus" ]]`

Comment: i already use this @pikand

Comment: Ok. In your example it's `if [[ "$c_name" != "$customer" ]]`

Comment: i try these two already but not working..!@pikand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your loop is the query `"select cus_name from $table_name;"`. This is selecting all the cus_name in the table and populating the array. In your above example when you are providing the first customer name again after entering the second customer, your query is fetching the following result

`++  'select cus_name from demo_table'
+ customer='ABC
BCD'`

This is why your if condition fails

`+ [[ ABC != \A\B\C\\B\C\D ]]`

To fix your problem change your query to below

`"select cus_name from $table_name where cus_name like '$c_name';")`

This will check if the customer exists in the DB and if the customer exists and will return the customer name. if ABC exists then it will return ABC and your if condition will work correctly.